# Updating child property from parent in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to be able to update a child component property from both the parent and itself according to the last event.

For example:

```
class MyParent extends Component {
  state ={
    text:"";
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <MyChild text={this.state.text} />
        <Button
          onPress={()=>this.setState({text:"parent"})}
          title="Update From Parent"
        />
     </View>
   );
  }
} 


class MyChild extends Component {
    state ={
      text:"";
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.text!== this.state.text) {
       this.setState({text:nextProps.text});
    }
}

render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {/* I want that the text field will be updated from the last event*/}
        <Text>{this.state.text}</Text>
        <Button
            onPress={()=>this.setState({text:"child"})}
            title="Update From Child"
        />
      </View>
   );
  }
}
```

The issue is that componentWillReceiveProps is triggered each time the setState is called so the text property takes the value from the parent and not from the child.

How can I achive this result?

Thanks a lot 
Elad

Answer (score 1):

Manage your `state` through `parent` component and `pass` the function that will update the `state` of `parent` component in `child` component

```
class MyParent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: "",
      updateParentState: (newState) => this.setState(newState)
    }
  }

  render() {
    let { text, updateParentState } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <MyChild data={{ text, updateParentState }} />
        <Button
          onPress={() => updateParentState({ text: "parent" })}
          title="Update From Parent"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}


class MyChild extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: props.data.text
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.text !== this.state.text) {
      this.setState({ text: nextProps.data.text });
    }
  }

  render() {
    let { updateParentState } = this.props.data;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.text}</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => updateParentState({ text: "child" })}
          title="Update From Child"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool , good idea. By the way I am curious why did you insert the updateParentState function into the state and not just added it directly to the class?

Comment: Yes, that's the option too. But I choose this way. No technical jargon. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this. in the setState call in child. please check if this is not the issue.

```
<Button
  onPress={()=>setState({text:"child"})}
  title="Update From Child"
/>
```

should be

```
<Button
  onPress={()=>this.setState({text:"child"})}
  title="Update From Child"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks it was a typo mistake. I wrote the example right here so I didn't check the example before. I fixed it.